# Angular : use filter on ng-options when using for(key,value)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a ListBox that i want to filter depending on a user Input, in order to display only "matches" posibility.

Unfortunatly, the "filter" only change the value display or don't work at all. I expect it's because I use for (key,value) and it have a different behaviour ?

```
<p>Filter : <input type="text" ng-model="FilterAttr"/> {{FilterAttr}}</p>
<select ng-options="value as (value.attr+ ' : ' +value.otherAttr) for (key,value) in CustomList | filter:{attr:FilterAttr}"
     size="4" ng-model="nevermind" ng-change="changeSensor(TyreDetails)">
</select>
```

here is a jsffidle : http://jsfiddle.net/hLywvam7/2/

Thank for any help.

Comment: filter only works on arrays. Suggest mapping the data to array first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) can only be applied to arrays, not objects.

Now either change "CustomList" format to Array or convert "CustomList" object to array like below

```
$scope.filterCustomList = function(items) {
    var result = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
        result[key] = value;
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: In my case, your fonction give the same result than the entry.
I replace `result = []` and `result.push(value)`

Comment: I have edited "result = []" in post. yes, can use push(value) only when key is not required